# Fix gap in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I remove the white space gap in each row element?

I have tried with `width: 1px` but that is not so elegant. Any better ideas?

[image]

Comment: Would you mind share the html and css code ?

Comment: It is considering the space from the th elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `padding` property, in this case `padding: none`. You can also try `margin: none` if it helps.

Some links:

- [padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)
- [margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a padding-left/padding-right or even a margin-left/margin-right. It can also help to make the text bigger with a font-size.